# Is there a faster algorithm for collision detection?

Tags: android, performance, collision-detection

I'm writing this game on Android where I have a bunch of characters moving around who collide with each other. Everything works fine but when I get passed a certain number of characters on the screen at the same time, the performance of the app gets hit severely. I did my tests and drawing is not causing the low frame rate, it is the algorithm for collision detection, since every time they move they have to check their location to all the other characters. So currently I'm just looping through them all for each character. Is there a way to improve on this? Is there a performance trick to collision detection on a big number of objects that I don't know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a technique based on a first broad-phase and second narrow-phase colission detection.

I'll quote some paragraps from: *Beginning Android Games*, by Mario Zechner.

> **Broad phase**: In this phase we try to figure out which objects can
>   potentially collide.  Imagine having 100 objects that could each
>   collide with each other. We’d need to perform 100 * 100 / 2 overlap
>   tests if we chose to naively test each object against each other
>   object. This naive overlap testing approach is of O(n^2) asymptotic
>   complexity, meaning  it would take n^2 steps to complete (it actually
>   finished in half that many steps, but the  asymptotic complexity
>   leaves out any constants). In a good, non-brute-force broad phase, we
>   try to  figure out which pairs of objects are actually in danger of
>   colliding. Other pairs (e .g., two objects that are too far apart for
>   a collision to happen) will not be checked . We can reduce the
>   computational load this way, as narrow-phase testing is usually pretty
>   expensive.
>
> **Narrow phase**: Once we know which pairs of objects can potentially
>   collide, we test  whether they really collide or not by doi ng an
>   overlap test of their bounding shapes.

The broad phase involves dividing the world in large cells, making some sort of grid.
Each cell has the exact same size, and the whole world is covered in cells. If two objects are not in the same cell, a narrow phase for those two objects is not needed.

Quote once again:

> All we  need to do is the following:
>
> - Update all objects in the world based on our physics and controller  step.
> - Update the position of each bounding shape of each  object according  to the object’s position. We can of  course also include the orientation  and scale as well here.
> - Figure out which cell or cells each object is contained in based on its  bounding shape, and add it to the  list of objects contained in those  cells.
> - Check for collisions, but only between object pairs that can collide (e.g.,  Goombas don’t collide with other Goombas) and are in the same cell.
>
> This is called a  spatial hash grid broad phase, and it is very easy to implement.  The first  thing we have to define is the size of each cell. This is highly dependent on the scale and units we use for our  game’s world.

It also depends on the bounding shape you're using.  A simple rectangle or circle around the characters and it's *euclidean distance* is one simple thing to calculate, but a finer shape (including details as "the head", "the legs" with little additional bounding shapes) will be more a lot more computationally expensive to calculate.

Comment: That was a quite clever technique. Spent hours last night refactoring the app to follow that method and let me tell ya: the hours were well worth it. The game is now butterly smooth. I guess that I should keep in mind this mechanism next time I start developing a game. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

If all objects are free to move to any part of the screen, then the best you can do is your `O(n^2)` algorithm. You can improve it by a constant factor by realizing that when you check if object A collides with object B, then you don't have to later check if object B collides with object A.

Answer (score 0):

enclose each character within a fixed size square. Before you check for character collision, check if the squares in which they are enclosed collide. If and only if the squares collide, there would be a chance for the characters to collide. Now checking for squares collision is easy as you have to just compare the x & y co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing into a broad phase and narrow phase as Federico suggests only helps if your collision detection algorithm is expensive, i.e. it's not a simple bounding box.

Fortunately there are other options.

You could try a collision mask technique. Since you don't seem to be limited by rendering speed, render a bounding box for each object into a hidden bitmap. Before rendering the next object, check the pixels at the four corners of its bounding box to see if they have already been written. You can even use a different colour for each object so that the colour tells you which object the collision was with.

Another popular trick is to simply not do every collision check every frame. For example, games like Super Mario Bros actually only check for collisions between the player and enemies every other frame. You can do a more advanced version where you check all objects in a round-robin fashion, doing as many as it can per frame. When things get busy each object might only be checked every other or even every third frame, but the player is unlikely to notice. This works best if your objects are not moving so fast that they can pass through each other one only one frame of collision.